# how can I force Spark executor to spawn more threads per task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am running a cluster of EMR Spark with this setup:

```
Master: 1 of m5.xlarge
Core:   4 of m5.xlarge

spark.executor.instances         4
spark.executor.cores             4
spark.driver.memory              11171M
spark.executor.memory            10356M
spark.emr.maximizeResourceAllocation true
spark.emr.default.executor.memory 10356M
spark.emr.default.executor.cores 4
spark.emr.default.executor.instances 4
```

where xlarge is an instance type which has 4 vCPU cores 16 GB memory.

Since I am using Spark to migrate database, the workload is very I/O intensive but not so much CPU intensive. I notice each executor node only spawns 4 threads (seems like 1 thread per vCPU core), while the CPU still has plenty of headroom.

Is there a way which allows me to force a higher thread allocation per executor node so that I can fully utilize my resources? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One **vCPU** can hold only one thread.

In case you have assign 4 vCPU to your executor it will never spawns more than 4 threads.

***For more detail***

**Calculation of vCPU & Cores**

First, we need to select a virtual server and CPU. For this example, we’ll select Intel Xeon E-2288G as the underlying CPU. Key stats for the Intel Xeon E-2288G include 8 cores / 16 threads with a 3.7GHz base clock and 5.0GHz turbo boost. There is 16MB of onboard cache.

**(16 Threads x 8 Cores) x 1 CPU = 128 vCPU**

[reference](https://www.datacenters.com/news/what-is-a-vcpu-and-how-do-you-calculate-vcpu-to-cpu)